# Export failed from CSV to MySQL using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to export a CSV file to MySQL using C# but failing every time I do that. I am getting an error as unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. Please help me.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string connectionStringMySql = "Server=000.000.000.00; Database=test; Uid=test; Pwd=tester;";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strCSVFile = "C:\\Users\\IT-Administrator\\Desktop\\Exploded.csv";

        MySqlConnection conn1 = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringMysql);

        string strLoadData = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + strCSVFile + "' INTO TABLE synctest.tickets FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' ignore 1 lines;";

        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(strLoadData, conn1);

        cmd1.CommandTimeout = 6000;

        cmd1.Connection = conn1;
        conn1.Open();
        cmd1.Prepare();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn1.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the connection string you're really using, or did you redact the actual IP from it?  If that's what you're using, then there's your problem.

Comment: What server is at `000.000.000.00`? Are you able to connect using a MySQL client of some sort?

Comment: connect string is not the real one it just an fake IP..

Comment: You might also have a firewall blocking the connection if you can connect from the server itself to the MySQL database (but not from your client). Check for port 3306

Answer (score 0):

Local infile must be on the mysql server, if it was a remote host it will fail.
on remote host directory must be writable by mysql user

I strongly recommend do not use infile bulk loads and dumps unless it was a server migration

sorry the poor english.